# How to use a local php file for fetch function?

Tags: react-native

I've tried [this](https://reactnativecode.com/react-native-insert-text-input-data-to-mysql-server/) and i think my problem is in the fetch function.

When I use the url from the site it works but when I use a local php file it doesn't work.

```
fetch(./submitData.php),{
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
       ...
   }
}
```

When I use the above code, I get the error:

*Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.string(java.lang.Object' on a null object reference*

**Edit:**

```
fetch('https://localhost/submitData.php', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
       ...
   }
}
```

Error: network request failed

Comment: It seems you forgot to use a quotes in your codes. Try something like this
`fetch('http://localhost/submitData.php')`
*Note : you cant run a PHP file directly like that,you need a webserver  to run it or PHP binary to execute it

Comment: @Hendri now it says Network request failed